# How to still using DNS even when switch the proxy in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox, dns, proxy

I'm using some DNS on my connection on Ubuntu 14 and then I want to still using it even I switch the proxy on foxyproxy. Can I do it?

Comment: I'm using OpenDns Familyshield but I need to use some proxy of my university to be able to get some scientific papers on web. So I'm using foxyproxy. I just want that the OpenDns block remain when I'm using the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google's DNS, 8.8.8.8, for example, try this one:
Advanced >> Network >> Connections >> No Proxy for: 8.8.8.8

see more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/No_Proxy_For_configuration

Comment: I tried and nothing happened...  :(

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of DNS is different for different types of proxies.

In case of an HTTP proxy:
Your HTTP request is sent to a HTTP proxy server which resolves the domain.
Since the proxy is forwarding the request to the actual destination server, only it needs to know the real IP of the destination host.

In case of a SOCKS proxy:
Firefox (by default) resolves DNS locally but it can be forced to resolve DNS trough a SOCKS proxy by entering about:config in the address bar and enabling the setting "network.proxy.socks_remote_dns".